# Delete all Group content controls only in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have looked all over for a solution, but for some reason I am not able to delete group content controls only in vba. I do not want to delete the contents within these controls, just the control itself. Here is the code I am using to currently isolate group content controls to delete:

```
Dim cc As ContentControl

  For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Group")
    cc.Delete
  Next
```

Does anyone know why this will not delete Group content controls? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little more, I realized that group content controls dont have a title. I thought the "Group" would be used for the tag, or title of the control, but it does not. Here is the updated code (but doesn't guarantee only group controls will be deleted).

```
Dim cc As ContentControl

  For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("")
    cc.Delete
  Next
```